# PostgreSQL: How to use char column containing a timestamp

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select, timestamp

I'm working with a PostgreSQL database that includes a char column containing textual timestamps in the format "Prefix: Wed May 7, 11:30AM-1:30PM". There are no years, all dates are assumed to be within the current year. I realize it would be easier to work with this data if it were in columns with a type of timestamp or date and time but I do not have any control over the database format, I have to work with what's there.

What I need to do is write a SELECT that returns only records with a specific prefix value (e.g. "public" vs "private") AND a time/date equal to later than the current time/date. This is a relatively large database with around 100,000 records and I need to be able to do the search quickly. Can anyone offer advice on the best way to achieve this? I've considered using a regex or a combination of to_date() and substring() but I'm uncertain how to proceed.

Bonus question: is there a way to Order the records sequentially by date and time using this field?

Comment: Unfortunately this is horrid design...with that format, you'll never be able to put a decent date index on the table and all queries are going to hurt from it. My first thought - have any ability to create your own datawarehouse and create an etl process to import this table?  We can get a query to read that date field and make sense of it, but I'm not sure if you'll ever see good speed without being able to alter that table

Comment: You have no year in your date time format.  How do you know what the date really is?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: "all dates are assumed to be within the current year"

Comment: @Twelfth, I agree about the design. Craziest thing I've ever seen but no chance I can get it changed. I can't create additional tables or databases. All I can do at this point is try to find the fastest SELECT I can come up with that works with the data as-is.

Comment: @steevithak - sometime you have to do what you have to do...I would make sure you advise whomever makes the descisions sorrounding this database that it is very poorly designed and without the mandate to change the structure, the speed is likely to remain quite slow. Dataloss as years pass (and quite likely functionality issues...what happens if you get two date/time entries that are identical, one from 2013 and 2014?) Any solution you come up with here is likely void in 6 months. Gordons solution looks good otherwise

Comment: Thanks for the potential solutions! Looks like everybody prefers using string splitting and date conversion functions over trying some kind of regex. I'm going to try these out tomorrow and try to do some performance testing to see what's fastest. I'll come back and select one of the answers tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this will work:

```
select split_part(col, ':', 1) as prefix,
       to_timestamp(to_char(now(), 'YYYY') || 
                    split_part(col, ':', 2),
                    'YYYY Dy Mon dd, HH:MIAM'
                   ) as DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to use the dates as a range, you can use Postgres range capabilities. (Or you could of course just set up start and end dates. Both are done in the example below.)

```
WITH initial_strings AS (
SELECT 'Public: Wed May 7, 11:30AM-1:30PM'::varchar as char_time),

split_up AS
(
SELECT
split_part(char_time, ':', 1) prefix,
split_part(split_part(char_time,',',2), '-', 1)::TIME start_time,
split_part(split_part(char_time,',',2), '-', 2)::TIME end_time,
to_timestamp(to_char(now(), 'YYYY') || 
            split_part(split_part(char_time,',',1), ':', 2),
            'YYYY Dy Mon dd'
            ) as the_day
FROM initial_strings),

new_format AS
(
SELECT 
prefix,
tstzrange((the_day + start_time),(the_day + end_time)) time_range,
the_day + start_time started_at,
the_day + end_time ended_at
FROM split_up
ORDER BY started_at) --Performs the required ordering

SELECT *
FROM new_format
WHERE prefix = 'Public'
AND started_at >= '2014-05-07';
```

This of course assumes that your times are always within the same day. If thats not the case, you'll have to be a little bit trickier with your splitting, but it should just be a slight modificaion of this.